# Can I use a model as Inline on a model where the foreign key is over another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This are my models:

```
class Image(models.Model):

class Size(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)

class Physical(models.Model):
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size)
```

I'm trying to add `Size` and `Physical` as an Inline on `ImageAdmin`. The user has to create some sizes, before he can add some physicals where he has to select an existing size of the image.

Is this possible?

Thanks and Regards,
Silvan

Comment: What're actual relationships among those models? Why does `Physical` refer to `Size`?

Comment: `Physical` is a real physical print of an image and depends on the size (e.g. S, M, L).

Comment: I tried to define the foreign key name like: `fk_name = 'size__image'` but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm on a totally wrong way here ;)